# Which font style in the Microsoft Office Software is the most similar to newpxtext and newpxmath

Tags: fonts, msword, powerpoint

I am using the `newpxtext` and the `newpxmath` packages for the font style in my document. I also need to make some pictures with Microsoft Office Software (mainly Powerpoint), and then put them in the document. I wish to have a unified font style in both the text and the picture in the document.

Hence, does anyone know which font style in Microsoft Office Software is the most similar to that in the `newpxtext`? Currently, I use the "Palatino Linotype", but is there other better one? Maybe some font style files needed to be installed manually are also thankful.

Besides, I also need to put some "Equation" in the Microsoft Office Software picture, and the "Palatino Linotype" seems can not be used in the "Equation". Currently, I use "Cambria Math", but there have some differences as the style of that in the `newpxmath`. Are there some other choices? Maybe some font style files needed to be installed manually are also thankful.

Thanks a lot for the detailed answer from David. I follow the guidelines, and it works well for the text with `fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre`. While, for the equation with `fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math`, there are some issues that exist.

If all the things in the equation are all letters, then it works well. While, if there are numbers or "," contained in the subscript or the superscript, then they do not show correctly.

I try this in PowerPoint 2021.

For example, this is the equation in the font `Cambria Math`, it shows correctly.
[image]

In the font `TeX Gyre Pagella Math`, it shows in this form, which is not the expected form, since the numbers and "," in the subscript and the superscript are not shown correctly.
[image]

Could you please help find out what may the problem be?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You could use TeX Gyre Pagella and TeX Gyre Pagella Math, which are the open type fonts used as the basis for newpx

Comment: Just to clarify what @DavidCarlisle means: you can install those fonts like you would any other system font and then use them directly in Powerpoint or Word.

Comment: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/tex-gyre/opentype

Comment: I don't use word and it's off topic here but your image suggests you are using tex gyre pagella math as a text font, don't do that use tex gyre pagella. just use the math font in the setting for math zones, not text font where you show _I_ B etc

Comment: Dear David, thank you very much for your reply, I will try as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newpx` is based on the TeX Gyre Pagella family of Opentype fonts that you can use directly in Word.

First install them. You can find them in your tex installation `fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre`  and `fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math`, just right click and `install` so they are available to windows applications not just TeX.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Selecting the math font is hidden away in a conversions arrow thing under equations.

Then just do whatever you would do (I have no idea how to use word:-) and produce text and math using TeX Gyre Pagella:

[image]

Comment: Dear David,

Thank you very much for your answer, it is very helpful.

It works well with the "fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre" after following your guidelines.

While, for the "fonts/opentype/public/tex-gyre-math", there are some problems.

I edited the original question above and described the problems, could you please help find the possible solutions?

Thank you very much in advance.